# Where did they go at the end of Repo Man?

Tags: magic, aliens

Where did [Otto and Miller](http://fusionanomaly.net/repomanmillerandotto.jpg) go in the Malibu at the end of 1984's [Repo Man](http://www.filmbunker.net/sites/default/files/styles/cartelgrande/public/cartel-repo-man.jpg)?

[image: Malibu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mars**, it seems.

The sequel to Repo Man, [Waldo's Hawaiian Holiday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldo%27s_Hawaiian_Holiday), was never filmed but was [produced as a graphic novel](http://www.gestaltcomics.com/store/waldo/).  The story concerns Otto's life after his return from 10 years on Mars, and his discoveries about the activities of Martians in Los Angeles:

> "In 1994, ten years after I made REPO MAN, I became interested in the
>   idea of a sequel. Specifically - what had happened to Otto, during his
>   ten-year absence from Earth? And what would he make of the changes
>   which had taken place in his absence? Otto, it would appear, has been
>   held prisoner, in great luxury, on the planet Mars. Now he has
>   returned to Earth, and changed his name -- to Waldo." - [Alex Cox](http://www.alexcox.com/dir_repoman.htm)